# Setting filters in the Open File dialog box with a wild card(*) in the middle in C

Tags: c++, file-io, wildcard

I'm trying to set up a filter for the OpenFile dialog box which has both the prefix and file type already preset, with the wild card in the middle. (Using VS08, cpp)

`FileFilter.Format("Prefix_(*.gdd)|Prefix_*.gdd|Any GDD File|*.gdd|all files|*.*|");`

`FileDialog = new CFileDialog(...);`

The problem is that the `Prefix_*.gdd` filter isn't showing any files even though there is one present.

The filter works for an Explorer search - should it work here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. The 'Prefix_' string, which was programatically generated, had the classic confusion between `date` and `data`, so the data files with date in their file names weren't found, leaving the OpenFile dialog empty.

It now appears to work properly.